# SonarQube 5.6.7 Jazz RTC SCM Plugin 1.1 SCM Stats page blank

Tags: version-control, statistics, sonarqube, rtc, ibm-jazz

Running SonarQube 5.6.7 with Jazz RTC plugin 1.1, when using a maven build to analysis an RTC project, the maven build and SonarQube analysis completes successfully but the SCM Stats page in SonarQube for that project is blank

Please advise how to resolve

Answer (score 0):

The [SonarQube Jazz RTC SCM Plugin](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-scm-jazzrtc) ([1.1 from July 2016](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-scm-jazzrtc/releases/tag/1.1)) still need to be run with a sonar scanner including the right parameters (as seen in [Analyzing with SonarQube Scanner](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner) for instance)

```
sonar.host.url
sonar.projectKey=my:project
sonar.projectName=My project
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
```

Those are the kind of parameters which enable the sonnar plugin to send back the analysis results to the Sonar server.